# How to get div class using label class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to access div class using label class. The Logic is on placing mouse over `<label class="name">`  `<div class="hidden">` is called. Please note `<li>` and `<div>` id is unqiue all the time

**HTML**

```
     <li id="132" class="main" ><label class="name">Ajay</label>   
    <div class="hidden" id="132" >
       <p>Some Msg!!<p>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li id="192"  class="main"> <label class="name">Raj</label>    
    <div class="hidden" id="192" >
       <p>Some Msg!!<p>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li id="231"  class="main" ><label class="name">David</label>    
    <div class="hidden" id="231" >
       <p>Some Msg!!<p>
    </div>
    </li>

   So on...
```

**Jquery**

```
    $('.name').hovercard({detailsHTML:$('.hidden').html()}) 
// on placing mouse on label <div class="hidden"> is called
```

Please help me out

Comment: Your markup is invalid (your `label` markup is *inside* the `li` opening tag), and your description doesn't match what your code says you're trying to do. Could you please fix the markup, and make sure that you're really using the terms "parent" and "child" correctly? (Note that `label class="name"` and `div class="hidden"` are, assuming what I believe the markup *should* be, *siblings*, neither parents nor children.)

Comment: Your `li id` and `div id` are identical. Is this intentional? If so, it's a bad practice since ID should be unique for each element.

Comment: append string in your loop for either li or div 's id ..bcz both of them are unique

Comment: And put your label outside li closing tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, and your description doesn't match what your code says you're trying to do. I'm guessing here that the markup in each case should look like this:

```
<li id="132" class="main"><label class="name">Ajay</label>
<div class="hidden" id="132" >
   <p>Some Msg!!<p>
</div>
</li>
```

If so, and if you're trying to call `hovercard` on `label.name` elements and include information from the `div.hidden` near them, you'd want something like this:

```
 $(".name").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hovercard({detailsHTML:$this.nextAll("div.hidden").html()});
 });
```

...because the `div` and the `label` are not in a parent/child relationship, they're *siblings*. You can't do this without the loop because we need to navigate.

---

Also note that using the same `id` value on both the `label` and the `div` is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique on the page. Also note that `id` values starting with digits are [valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), but they're [invalid in HTML4 and earlier](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), and they're [invalid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). As you're using jQuery, that means you probably use a lot of CSS selectors to interact with your structure. Since all-numeric `id` values are invalid in CSS, they're invalid in CSS selectors, and you'll just end up causing yourself trouble.

Answer (score 3):

As T.J said, your markup is invalid. With the correct markup you can achieve this with only HTML and CSS.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<li id="231"  class="main">
   <label class="name">David</label>
   <div class="hidden" id="231" >
      <p>Some Msg!!<p>
   </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
div.hidden {
   display: none;
}
li.main:hover div.hidden {
   display: block;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MWbS4/